# Power BI Measure Breaks Parent/Child Relationship

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a report with a parent/child relationship between 2 tables. When I select the parent in the first table, the associated child objects are successfully displayed in the second table.

Now I've created a measure to calculate a value in the child table. When I add that to the child table it returns **all** child rows, regardless of what is selected in the parent table. The code is as follows:

```
Measure 2 = 7-MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE('Child'[Estimated Date]))
```

Interestingly, the following code works just fine and returns the appropriate child rows:

```
Measure 2 = MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE('Child'[Estimated Date]))
```

Comment: I should add that if I don't use SelectedValue, then the [Estimated Date] field isn't available to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does using CALCULATE and an IF statement solve your issue?

```
Measure 2 = IF(NOT(ISBLANK(CALCULATE(MAX('Child'[Estimated Date])))), 7 - MONTH(CALCULATE(MAX('Child'[Estimated Date]))))
```

Comment: unfortunately no.

Comment: @dijitalD Try my updated answer :)

Comment: Eureka! that did it! Thank you for the help. So it is the blank fields that are somehow screwing up the entire formula? this seems insane to me.

Comment: I've noticed that with measures there is often weird behavior where non-blank output isn't filtered from a table. So basically, since you had the "7 - x", then you were getting "7 - BLANK() = 7" as an output on filtered rows. Since this is a non-blank answer, it's not filtered from the table. 

The IF statement was basically just saying to only return output for non-blank input. If it's confusing then it's probably because I'm not 100% sure of the reasoning either :/